# Get few rows from another site in PHP

Tags: php

I want to get this url rows: https://robot.your-server.de/order/market/country/US with pagination with php and get it in my website.

Answer (score 1):

Scraping is not the better thing to do, have you check if this site has an API?

If not, you can use `fil_get_contents` to load all the page content as a string. One you have all the HTML as a string, DomDocument can help you to navigate to the first row.

Because this is scrapping I'll not show code example.

See [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).